# Square Space Code Injection D3 not defined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, squarespace

Recently I've gotten my code working within d3.JS and would like to implement it into a square space site that a friend has been working on. Ive been trying to implement my d3 js code into square space with little to no luck. I've tried code blocks as well as injecting the library then implemented my code through code blocks, but I've gotten nothing. It just states that d3 is not defined. Which is probably a hint that the d3 library isn't running or isn't running first. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? The code below is a my current attempt at code injection.

````
<script type="module" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script>
console.log("map script beginning");
const data = {
    segments:
        [
            {
                name: "Venture Capital / Business Development-A",
                color: "#ff450c"
            },
            {
                name: "Research & Development-A",
                color: "#4ad2ce"
            },
            {
                name: "Biomanufacturing-A",
                color: "#ffd31a"
            },
            {
                name: "Lab Administration / Lab Operations-A",
                color: "#7c1f94"
            },
            {
                name: "Venture Capital / Business Development-M",
                color: "#ee5325"
            },
            {
                name: "Research & Development-M",
                color: "#58c4c1"
            },
            {
                name: "Biomanufacturing-M",
                color: "#fcc733"
            },
            {
                name: "Lab Administration / Lab Operations-M",
                color: "#752b88"
            },
            {
                name: "Venture Capital / Business Development-E",
                color: "#da5e39"
            },
            {
                name: "Research & Development-E",
                color: "#63b9b7"
            },
            {
                name: "Biomanufacturing-E",
                color: "#e8bd47"
            },
            {
                name: "Lab Administration / Lab Operations-E",
                color: "#70347f"
            },
        ],
    careerPaths: [
        {
            name: "Venture Capital / Business Development",
            posX: 0,
            posY: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Research & Development",
            posX: 0,
            posY: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Biomanufacturing",
            posX: 0,
            posY: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Lab Administration / Lab Operations",
            posX: 0,
            posY: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        }
    ],
    careerStage: [
        {
            name: "Advanced",
            posX: 0,
            posY: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Middle",
            posX: 0,
            posY: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Entry",
            posX: 0,
            posY: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        }

    ],
    jobs: [
        //Test Position
        {
            name: "Research Intern",
            posX: 400,
            posY: 700,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            salary: "$25/y",
            eduReq: "High School Diploma",
            eduDes: "Bachelors in Science",
            reqExp: "Beat Super Mario",
            desExp: "Beat Super Mario 2"
            ,
            id: 0,
            yAdjustment: 0



        },
        {
            name: "Research Associate",
            posX: 400,
            posY: 500,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            salary: "$25/y",
            eduReq: "High School Diploma",
            eduDes: "Bachelors in Science",
            reqExp: "Beat Super Mario",
            desExp: "Beat Super Mario 2"
            ,
            id: 1,
            yAdjustment: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Venture Capital Associate",
            posX: 190,
            posY: 640,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            salary: "$25/y",
            eduReq: "High School Diploma",
            eduDes: "Bachelors in Science",
            reqExp: "Beat Super Mario",
            desExp: "Beat Super Mario 2"
            ,
            id: 2,
            yAdjustment: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Biomenufacturing Associate",
            posX: 650,
            posY: 500,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            salary: "$25/y",
            eduReq: "High School Diploma",
            eduDes: "Bachelors in Science",
            reqExp: "Beat Super Mario",
            desExp: "Beat Super Mario 2"
            ,
            id: 3,
            yAdjustment: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Biomenufacturing CEO",
            posX: 650,
            posY: 200,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            salary: "$25/y",
            eduReq: "High School Diploma",
            eduDes: "Bachelors in Science",
            reqExp: "Beat Super Mario",
            desExp: "Beat Super Mario 2"
            ,
            id: 4,
            yAdjustment: 0
        }
        // Venture Capital / Business Development Positions
        //Entry
        , {
            name: "Management Consultant Entry-Level",
            posX: 55,
            posY: 640,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            salary: "N/A",
            eduReq: "Bachelor's Degree",
            eduDes: "Master's or PhD preferred",
            reqExp: "None",
            desExp: "Often hired right out of college"
            ,
            id: 5,
            yAdjustment: 0
        }
        //Mid
        , {
            name: "Analyst",
            posX: 60,
            posY: 510,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            salary: "N/A",
            eduReq: "Bachelor's Degree",
            eduDes: "MBA or PhD",
            reqExp: "Early stage diligence or scouting experience",
            desExp: "Experience in external innovation sourcing and evaluating"
            ,
            id: 6,
            yAdjustment: 0
        }
        , {
            name: "Management Consultant Mid-level",
            posX: 160,
            posY: 510,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            salary: "N/A",
            eduReq: "Bachelor's Degree",
            eduDes: "Master's or PhD or MD preferred",
            reqExp: "Consulting/Biotech/Pharma or startup experience preferred",
            desExp: "Experience in external innovation sourcing and evaluating"
            ,
            id: 7,
            yAdjustment: 0
        }
        , {
            name: "Research Director",
            posX: 60,
            posY: 410,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            salary: "N/A",
            eduReq: "Bachelor's Degree",
            eduDes: "Master's or PhD or MD preferred",
            reqExp: "Leading research",
            desExp: "Having scientific publications and track record of interesting research that translates to potential products"
            ,
            id: 8,
            yAdjustment: 0
        }
        , {
            name: "Business Development Scout",
            posX: 160,
            posY: 410,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            salary: "N/A",
            eduReq: "Bachelor's Degree",
            eduDes: "Master'r or PhD preferred",
            reqExp: "Understanding of biotech or pharma",
            desExp: "Scouting experience preferred"
            ,
            id: 9,
            yAdjustment: 0
        }
        //Advanced
        , {
            name: "Principal/ Associate",
            posX: 200,
            posY: 150,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            salary: "N/A",
            eduReq: "MBA, PhD or MD usually required",
            eduDes: "MBA, PhD or MD usually required",
            reqExp: "Sourcing and supporting scientific diligence and several years of experience in VC",
            desExp: "Board experience desired but not required",
            id: 10,
            yAdjustment: 0
        }
        , {
            name: "Venture Capitalist Partner",
            posX: 120,
            posY: 260,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            salary: "N/A",
            eduReq: "MBA, PhD or MD usually required",
            eduDes: "MBA, PhD or MD usually required",
            reqExp: "Successful portfolio of investments",
            desExp: "Board experience required.  Connections for fundraising ",
            id: 11,
            yAdjustment: 0
        }
        , {
            name: "Business Director Transaction Lead",
            posX: 40,
            posY: 150,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            salary: "N/A",
            eduReq: "Bachelor's Degree",
            eduDes: "MBA, PhD or MD preferred",
            reqExp: "BD experience",
            desExp: "Understanding of biotech or pharma",
            id: 12,
            yAdjustment: 0
        }



    ],
    links: [
        {
            source: 0,
            target: 1
        },
        {
            source: 0,
            target: 2
        },
        {
            source: 0,
            target: 3
        },
        {
            source: 5,
            target: 6
        },
        {
            source: 5,
            target: 7
        }

    ]
}

//setting up svg
const width = 1200;
const height = 800;
const body = d3.select("body")
    .style("-moz-user-select", "none")
    .style("-khtml-user-select", "none")
    .style("-webkit-user-select", "none")
    .style("user-select", "none")

var wrapper = body.append("div")
    .attr("id", "wrapper");
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);



let currentSource = null;

//creating ToolTip Default
const tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .style("background-color", "cornsilk")
    .style("border", "solid 3px black")
    .style("border-radius", "5px")
    .style("padding", "5px")
    .style("max-width", "250px")
    .style("viibility", "hidden")
    .style("text-align", "center")
    .style("display","none")
    .html(`
        <h3 class="toolTipHTML" id="position">NULL</h3>
        <h5 class="toolTipHTML" id="salary">Salary: NULL</h5>
        <h5 class="toolTipHTML" id="reqEDU">Required Eduction: NULL</h5>
        <h5 class="toolTipHTML" id="desEDU">Desired Eduction: NULL</h5>
        <h5 class="toolTipHTML" id="reqEXP">Required Expirence: NULL</h5>
        <h5 class="toolTipHTML" id="desEXP">Desired Expirence: NULL</h5>
        `)
let toolTipHTML = d3.selectAll(".toolTipHTML")
    .style("border-bottom", "2px solid black");

const dataSegments = svg.selectAll("segment").data(data.segments);
const dataTopLabel = svg.selectAll("tLabel").data(data.careerPaths);
const dataSideLabel = svg.selectAll("sLabel").data(data.careerStage);
const dataJobs = svg.selectAll("job").data(data.jobs);
const dataLinks = svg.selectAll("link").data(data.links);
let globalLaneWidth;
let globalLaneHeight;
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("fill", "grey")
    .attr("stroke-width", "6px")
    .attr("stroke", "black");
swimingLaneCreation(4, 3);
topLabels();
sideLabel();

jobsCreation();



svg.selectAll("#diagram")
    .attr("transform", "translate(15,15)")

    //ensuring on hover functions as well as animaitons are executed
let jobs = d3.selectAll("#job")
.on("mouseover", function (d) {
    //obtains the data associated with this specfic node and feeds this into the html elemnt
    //This will display the appropraite data associated with each of the nodes
    let overNodeData = d3.select(d.path[1]).datum();
    tooltip.html(`
    <h3 class="toolTipHTML" id="position">${overNodeData.name}</h3>
    <h5 class="toolTipHTML" id="salary">Salary: ${overNodeData.salary}</h5>
    <h5 class="toolTipHTML" id="reqEDU">Required Eduction: ${overNodeData.eduReq}</h5>
    <h5 class="toolTipHTML" id="desEDU">Desired Eduction: ${overNodeData.eduDes}</h5>
    <h5 class="toolTipHTML" id="reqEXP">Required Expirence: ${overNodeData.reqExp}</h5>
    <h5 class="toolTipHTML" id="desEXP">Desired Expirence: ${overNodeData.desExp}</h5>
    `)
    .style("display","block");
    d3.selectAll(".toolTipHTML").style("border-bottom", "2px solid black");
    //controls the opacity animation that will have the tooltip fade in and out
    tooltip.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0.95);
})
.on("mousemove", function (event) {

    let toolTipBox = document.querySelector(".tooltip");
    let currentWidth = toolTipBox.offsetWidth;
    let currentHeight = toolTipBox.offsetHeight;

    tooltip.style("top", `${event.pageY - (currentHeight + currentHeight / 8)}px`)//ensures that the tooltip is slightly above the cursor
        .style("left", `${event.pageX - (currentWidth / 2)}px`);//ensures that the tooltip is in the center of the cursor
})
.on("mouseout", function () {

    //the tooltip can interfere with onhover functionality so the tooltip is move up and away from the diagram
    tooltip.transition()
        .delay(150)
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0)
        //.style("top", `${-height}px`)
        .on("end",function(){tooltip.style("display","none")});
});




function jobsCreation() {
    let currentGElement = null;
    let enteringText = dataJobs
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.posX })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.posY })
        .attr("id", "job")
        .attr("class", function (d) { return d.name.split(" ").join("") })
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.posX })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.posY })
        .attr("id", "jobText")
        .attr("class", function (d) { return d.name })
        .text(function (d) { return d.name })
        .call(wrap, 30)
        .each(function (d, i) {

            let currnetText = d3.select(this);
            let objectToAppend = d3.select(this.parentNode);
            let padding = 20;
            let jobText = d3.selectAll("#jobText")
            let pastX = null;
            let newX = null;
            let pastbbox = objectToAppend.node().getBBox();
            objectToAppend.append("rect")
                .attr("id", "dumbRect")
                .attr("x", function () {
                    pastX = pastbbox.x - (padding / 2);
                    return pastbbox.x - (padding / 2);
                })
                .attr("y", function () { return pastbbox.y - (padding / 2) })
                .attr("width", function (d) { return pastbbox.width + padding })
                .attr("height", function (d) { return pastbbox.height + padding })
                .remove();

            let tspans = d3.selectAll(this.children).style("text-anchor", "middle");
            let bbox = objectToAppend.node().getBBox();
            newX = bbox.x - (padding / 2);

            let difference = Math.abs(pastX - newX);
            objectToAppend.append("rect")
                .attr("x", bbox.x - (padding / 2))
                .attr("y", bbox.y - (padding / 2))
                .attr("width", function (d) { d.width = bbox.width; return bbox.width + padding })
                .attr("height", function (d) { d.height = bbox.height; return bbox.height + padding })
                .attr("rx", 6)
                .attr("ry", 6)
                .attr("id", "jobBox")
                .style("fill", "white")
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .style("stroke-width", "1.5px");
            objectToAppend.attr("transform", `translate(${difference},${-objectToAppend.datum().yAdjustment})`);




        })
        .raise();
    d3.selectAll("#job")
        .on("click", generateLinks);

}
function generateLinks() {
    let source = null;
    for (let x = 0; x < data.jobs.length; x++) {
        let selectedClass = d3.select(this.children[1]).attr("class");
        if (data.jobs[x].name == selectedClass) {//get the second child element this will ALWAYS be the text element
            source = x;
        }

    }
    lineCreation(source);
    d3.selectAll("#job").raise();


};
function lineCreation(source) {
    currentSource = source;
    svg.selectAll("#jobBox").style("fill", "white");
    svg.selectAll("#jobBox").style("opacity", "0.3");
    svg.selectAll("#jobText").style("opacity", "0.3");
    svg.selectAll("line").remove();
    let sourceX = null;
    let sourceY = null;
    let targetX = null;
    let targetY = null;

    let sourceFound = false;
    let entering = dataLinks
        .enter()
        .each(function (d) {
            const objectToAppend = d3.select(this);
            if (d.source == source) {

                sourceX = (data.jobs[d.source].posX + (data.jobs[d.source].width / 2));
                sourceY = (data.jobs[d.source].posY - (data.jobs[d.source].height / 2) - 1);
                targetX = (data.jobs[d.target].posX + (data.jobs[d.target].width / 2));
                targetY = (data.jobs[d.target].posY - (data.jobs[d.target].height / 2));
            }
            objectToAppend.append("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("x1", sourceX)
                .attr("y1", sourceY)
                .attr("x2", sourceX)
                .attr("y2", sourceY)
                .attr("stroke-width", "3px")
                .attr("stroke", "white")
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .transition()
                .duration(1500)
                .attr("x2", targetX)
                .attr("y2", targetY);

        });


    selectedNodes();

}
function swimingLaneCreation(vertLaneNum, horiLaneNum) {
    let currentPosX = 0;
    let currentPosY = 50;
    const laneWidth = (width - 80) / vertLaneNum;
    const laneHeight = (height - 80) / horiLaneNum;
    globalLaneWidth = laneWidth;
    globalLaneHeight = laneHeight;
    const numOfLanes = vertLaneNum * horiLaneNum;
    let modeCounter = horiLaneNum;
    const firstRowHeight = laneHeight + 50;
    const firstColumnWidth = laneWidth + 50;
    let entering = dataSegments
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (a, i) {
            if (i == 0) {
                return currentPosX;
            }
            else if (i % vertLaneNum == 0) {
                currentPosX = 0;
                return currentPosX;
            }
            else {
                currentPosX += laneWidth;
                return currentPosX;
            }
        })
        .attr("y", function (a, i) {
            if (i == 0) {
                return currentPosY;
            }
            else if (i % vertLaneNum == 0) {
                currentPosY += laneHeight;

                return currentPosY;
            }
            else {
                return currentPosY;
            }
        })
        .attr("width", `${laneWidth}`)
        .attr("height", `${laneHeight}`)
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return d.color;
        })
        .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("id", "diagram");
};
function topLabels() {
    let currentPosX = 0;
    const currentPosY = 0;
    let currentWidth = globalLaneWidth;
    const currentHeight = 50;

    let entering = dataTopLabel
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "careerLabelV")
        .attr("id", "diagram")

    entering.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d, i) {
            if (i == 0) {
                d.posY = currentPosY;
                d.posX = currentPosX;
                return currentPosX;
            }
            else {
                currentPosX += currentWidth;
                d.posX = currentPosX;
                return currentPosX;
            }
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) { d.posY = currentPosY; return currentPosY; })
        .attr("width", function (d) { d.width = currentWidth; return currentWidth })
        .attr("height", function (d) { d.height = currentHeight; return currentHeight })
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("id", "vRect");


    let positionX = 0;
    let positionY = 0;
    entering
        .append("text")
        .text(function (d) { return d.name })
        .each(function (d) {

            let currentText = d3.select(this);
            let objectToAppend = d3.select(this.parentNode);

            let bbox = currentText.node().getBBox();//bbox is created to get the demensions and position of each of the labels

            let newPosX = d.posX + (d.width - bbox.width) / 2;//the difference in width /2 will give us the centered X
            let newPosY = d.posY + (d.height - (bbox.height));//the differnce in height will give you 

            currentText
                .attr("x", function (d) { return newPosX })//gets x position from width and increasing starting at zero transformation already accounted for
                .attr("y", function (d) { return newPosY });//accounting for transformation

            currentText.raise();
        });


    d3.selectAll(".careerLabel");
}

function sideLabel() {
    const currentPosX = width - 50 - (2 * 15);//the width of the side labels is 50 and adjustment for the transformation of 15
    let currentPosY = 50;
    const currentHeight = globalLaneHeight;
    const currentWidth = 50;
    let entering = dataSideLabel
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "careerLabelH")
        .attr("id", "diagram");

    entering.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) { d.posX = currentPosX; return currentPosX })
        .attr("y", function (d, i) {
            if (i == 0) {

                d.posY = currentPosY;
                return currentPosY;
            }
            else {
                currentPosY += globalLaneHeight;
                d.posY = currentPosY;
                return currentPosY;
            }
        })
        .attr("width", function (d) { d.width = currentWidth; return currentWidth })
        .attr("height", function (d) { d.height = globalLaneHeight; return globalLaneHeight })
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
        .attr("stroke", "black");

    entering.append("text")
        .text(function (d) { return d.name })
        .each(function (d) {
            let currentText = d3.select(this);
            let parentNode = d3.select(this.parentNode);
            let bbox = currentText.node().getBBox();

            //because the items are rotated 90 degrees height is affecting the x axis instead of the Y and vis versa so the differnce is the width - text(height)
            let newPosX = d.posX + (d.width - bbox.height) / 2;
            let newPosY = d.posY + (d.height - bbox.width) / 2;

            /*
            implementing the transformation (unlike in other 
            cases where objects have been moved globally)
            we must transform locally so rotation occours
            around the text origin
            */

            currentText
                .attr("transform", function (d) { return `translate(${newPosX},${newPosY}) rotate(90)` });
        })
}

function linkRemoval() {
    svg.selectAll("line").remove();
    svg.selectAll("#jobBox").style("fill", "white");
    svg.selectAll("#jobBox").style("opacity", "1.0");
    svg.selectAll("#jobText").style("opacity", "1.0");
}
d3.selectAll("#diagram").on("click", linkRemoval);
function selectedNodes() {
    dataLinks
        .enter()
        .each(function (d, i) {
            //if the source has been found this means the node has targets and these will be highlighted as well
            if (d.source == currentSource) {
                let sourceNode = d3.select(`.${data.jobs[currentSource].name.split(" ").join("")}`).select("rect")
                .transition()
                .duration(600)
                .style("fill", "skyblue").style("opacity", "1.0");

                let targetNodes = d3.select(`.${data.jobs[d.target].name.split(" ").join("")}`).select("rect")
                .transition()
                .duration(600)
                .style("fill", "PaleVioletRed").style("opacity", "1.0");

                let sourceText = d3.select(`.${data.jobs[currentSource].name.split(" ").join("")}`).select("text")
                .transition()
                .duration(600)
                .style("opacity", "1.0");

                let targetText = d3.select(`.${data.jobs[d.target].name.split(" ").join("")}`).select("text")
                .transition()
                .duration(600)
                .style("opacity", "1.0");
            }
            //in the event that the node has no target it. It will simply be the only highlighted node
            else if(d.source != currentSource && data.jobs[currentSource].name != null){
                let sourceNode = d3.select(`.${data.jobs[currentSource].name.split(" ").join("")}`).select("rect")
                .transition()
                .duration(600)
                .style("fill", "skyblue").style("opacity", "1.0");

                let sourceText = d3.select(`.${data.jobs[currentSource].name.split(" ").join("")}`).select("text")
                .transition()
                .duration(600)
                .style("opacity", "1.0");
            }
        });
};

/*Citing code (Mike, B (Feb 2022) D3 JS V3. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321)
this is code is used to wrap text in d3 js based on spacing
if their is a space within the text this will generate a new line*/
function wrap(text, width) {
    text.each(function () {
        var text = d3.select(this),
            words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
            word,
            line = [],
            lineNumber = 0,
            lineHeight = 17.6, // px converted EM to PX for the sake of readjusting node Y position
            x = text.attr("x"),
            y = text.attr("y"),
            dy = 0,
            tspan = text.text(null)
                .append("tspan")
                .attr("x", x)
                .attr("y", y)
                .attr("dy", function (d) { return dy + "px" });
        while (word = words.pop()) {
            line.push(word);
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                line.pop();
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                line = [word];
                tspan = text.append("tspan")
                    .attr("x", function (d) {
                        let newNumber = parseInt(x);
                        let addition = newNumber + 30;
                        return parseInt(newNumber)
                    })
                    .attr("y", y)
                    .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "px")
                    .text(word);
            }

        }

        /*
        the code used to wrap text within the each of the job nodes also displaces them
        from their original position we store the readjustment of the Y position within the 
        node to use later in job creation to re-adjust the position to its proper location
        */
        let adjustedY = lineNumber * lineHeight + dy;
        let parent = d3.select(this.parentNode);
        d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().yAdjustment = adjustedY;
    });
}
console.log("map script ending");
</script>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly sure why but it appears that module has an effect on which script goes first i therefore changed my code so d3 js was not type module but my javascript was type module. Sorry still new to javascript could anyone tell me why module has an effect on which script loading first?

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script>
....
</script>
```